# Are there any recorded cases of hearing the outside world while in a coma?

Tags: consciousness, hearing

There are plenty of stories flying around of people having been in a coma, but able to hear the outside world. They usually include either hearing malicious things said by staff, or encouragement by loved ones.
Are **any** of these cases recorded and verified, not just apocryphal?

Comment: Changed your tags and "proven" to "verified" (since some unnecessary epistemological concerns may arise from strong interpretations of "proof"). My edits weren't essential though, so feel free to revert if you object to anything. Was tempted to add the [tag:sleep] tag, but probably don't want to conflate sleep with coma states...

Comment: @NickStauner Perfect! I was trying to think of a better word than "proven", and that fit the bill excellently.

Comment: Monti, M.M., et al (2010). Willful modulation of brain activity in disorders of consciousness. The New England Journal of Medicine, 362(7), 579-589. http://www.google.com/url?url=http://scholar.google.com/scholar_url%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dhttp://www.researchgate.net/publication/41405188_Willful_modulation_of_brain_activity_in_disorders_of_consciousness/file/e0b49514d6c9744332.pdf%26sa%3DX%26scisig%3DAAGBfm2GIdXAuKTXUddfcdtab_Oh7AlhRA%26oi%3Dscholarr&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=X&ei=9uuEU9_HKtHhsATso4HABQ&ved=0CCgQgAMoADAA&usg=AFQjCNEwsEPlJgl3hfDce2AoTO73GdBdqw

Answer (score 2):

Here's a study on Brain Response to One's Own Name in Vegetative State, Minimally Conscious State, and Locked-in Syndrome:
http://archneur.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=791093

> **Background**  A major challenge in the management of severely
>   brain-injured patients with altered states of consciousness is to
>   estimate their residual perception of the environment.
>
> **Objective**  To investigate the integrity of detection of one's own name
>   in patients in a behaviorally well-documented vegetative state (VS),
>   patients in a minimally conscious state (MCS), and patients with
>   locked-in syndrome.
>
> **Design**  We recorded the auditory evoked potentials to the patient's
>   own name and to 7 other equiprobable first names in 15 brain-damaged
>   patients.
>
> **Results**  A P3 component was observed in response to the patient's name
>   in all patients with locked-in syndrome, in all MCS patients, and in 3
>   of 5 patients in a VS. P3 latency was significantly (P<.05) delayed
>   for MCS and VS patients compared with healthy volunteers.
>
> **Conclusions**  These results suggest that partially preserved semantic
>   processing could be observed in noncommunicative brain-damaged
>   patients, notably for the detection of salient stimuli, such as the
>   subject's own name. This function seems delayed in MCS and (if
>   present) in VS patients. More important, a P3 response does not
>   necessarily reflect conscious perception and cannot be used to
>   differentiate VS from MCS patients.